# gnupg giving me Windows error 5 access denied

Tags: python, gnupg

I am very new to gpg keys and In trying to figure out how to use the gnupg python module I cant get past a access denied error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pgptest.py", line 3, in <module>
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='C:/Users/Admin/gnupg')
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg-1.4.0-py2.7.egg\gnupg\gnupg.py", lin
e 120, in __init__
    use_agent=use_agent,)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg-1.4.0-py2.7.egg\gnupg\_meta.py", lin
e 214, in __init__
    self._check_sane_and_get_gpg_version()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg-1.4.0-py2.7.egg\gnupg\_meta.py", lin
e 481, in _check_sane_and_get_gpg_version
    proc.terminate()
  File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 1002, in terminate
    _subprocess.TerminateProcess(self._handle, 1)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

I am just using:

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='C:/Users/Admin/gnupg')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What user are you trying to access to files with? Seems you're not having read permissions, as indicated very clearly in the error message.

Comment: Admin user. I opened cmd as admin as well still giving me the error.

Comment: Verify the folder and file permissions. Can you open them with a text editor? Are you sure about that path? The default GnuPG home directory in Windows is located somewhere else.

Comment: oops ya i didnt write the whole path. Its C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/.gnupg. I verified the folder and file permissions.

Comment: Reading the traceback again, it seems the GnuPG egg already fails at calling GnuPG for "checking sanity and version". Might be a problem with your GnuPG installation, but I can't tell anything further without hands-on debugging.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the parameters are named correctly, or the library will miscalculate the command line invocation, which will typically result in an Access Denied / Permission Denied error.

In this case, it should have been `gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=...)`, i.e. **gnupghome** rather than **homedir**.